# libxml2: xpath relative to sub node

Tags: xpath, libxml2

Given the xml file

```
<a>
   <b>
      <d>v</d>
   </b>
   <c>
      <d>v</d>
   </c>
</a>
```

And the xpath "//d/text()"

I want to apply the xpath only to c and not to the whole document.

This has to work with libxml2 2.7.6

Doing this does not work;

```
xmlNodePtr node = <node pointer to c>
xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext( node->doc );
xpathCtx->node = node;

xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression ( "//d/text()", xpathCtx);
```

Returned xpathObj contains refences to both /a/b/d and /a/c/d. Only /a/c/d was expected.

Comment: xmlXPathNodeEval() is a better option.
See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627357/how-to-restrict-an-xpath-via-xmlxpathnodeeval-to-a-subtree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with:

```
xmlNodePtr node = <node pointer to c>

xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext( node->doc );

//Update the document to set node as root
xmlNodePtr myParent = node->parent;
xmlNodePtr originalRootElement = xmlDocGetRootElement( node->doc );
xmlDocSetRootElement( node->doc, node );

xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression ( "//d/text()", xpathCtx);

//xpathObj contains only /a/c/d, as expected

//restore the xml document
xmlDocSetRootElement( originalRootElement->doc, originalRootElement );
xmlAddChild( myParent, node );
```

Tested with valdrind.

The above example gives just the idea. In the following the complete implementation (thanks to Julo for his comment):

```
//Update Doc to support xpath on logical root node and restore the document structure at scope exit
class XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit {
public:
    XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit(  _xmlDoc* doc, _xmlNode* logicalRootNode) :
            _doc                ( doc              ),
            _logicalRootNode    ( logicalRootNode  ),
            _originalRootElement( 0 ),
            _refParent          ( 0 ),
            _refPrevSibling     ( 0 ),
            _refNextSibling     ( 0 ),
            _toRestore(false)
{
    _originalRootElement = xmlDocGetRootElement( doc );
    _refParent = _logicalRootNode->parent;
    _refPrevSibling = _logicalRootNode->prev;
    _refNextSibling = _logicalRootNode->next;

    if ( _logicalRootNode != _originalRootElement ) {
        xmlDocSetRootElement( _doc, _logicalRootNode );
        _toRestore = true;
    }

}

~XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit() {

    if ( _toRestore ) { 

        //Restore the root node
        xmlDocSetRootElement( _doc, _originalRootElement );

        //Restore the node at its original place
        if ( 0 != _refPrevSibling ) {
            xmlAddNextSibling( _refPrevSibling, _logicalRootNode );

        } else if ( 0 != _refNextSibling )  {
            xmlAddPrevSibling( _refNextSibling, _logicalRootNode );

        } else {
            xmlAddChild( _refParent, _logicalRootNode );
        }
    }
}
private:
    XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit() ; // not implemented
    XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit(const XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit &) ; // not implemented
    XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit & operator= (const XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit &) ; // not implemented
private:
    _xmlDoc* _doc;
    _xmlNode* _logicalRootNode;
    _xmlNode* _originalRootElement;
    _xmlNode* _refParent;
    _xmlNode* _refPrevSibling;
    _xmlNode* _refNextSibling;
    bool _toRestore;
};

//Somewhere in the code...
xmlNodePtr node = <node pointer to c>

xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext( node->doc );

//Here set the _rootNodePtr as the root of the document to use xpath on your "logical" root
//At scope exit the document's structure will be restored.
XmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit xmlDoc_UpdateDocAndRestoreAtScopeExit( node->doc, node );

xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression ( "//d/text()", xpathCtx);
//xpathObj contains only /a/c/d, as expected
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but remember that this is not the best one way. I would not recommend _(at least not as universal solution)_. Because this solution reorders items. When there are more items on the level of "`d`"  let's call them "`d, e, f`" _(can represent only different data with identical tag names)_, This solution make from items ordered as "`d, e, f`" a group of items ordered as follow: "`e, f, d`".

Comment: Hi Julo, thank you for your comment. I've updated the solution to show how to fix the issue you mentioned.

Comment: Nice fix. _(Different than my "order change" fix.)_ I need this _(or similar)_ functionality for C14N _(canonization)_ functions, since for unknown reasons xpath do not work as needed. Lets hope that the current behaviour of libxml2 do not change on _(newly)_ adjacent text nodes when "in-between node" is removed. Currently the nodes are not merged. But the comments for "addNode" functions says, that adjacent text nodes are merged. _(Even my fix is not universal and would in this case cause change in XML document. But since in my case there is only white space TEXT node this is not a problem.)_

Answer (score 4):

Use the path `.//d` or `.//d/text()` if you want to find descendants relative to another node. A path starting with `//d` searches all `d` descendant elements of the root node (also called document node).

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you for your reply.
In my specific case I need to force libxml2 to believe the root node is c.
In particular I receive as input the xpath "//d/text()" by external client that "see" c as the root tag. So I can't tell him "pass me .//d/text() instead of //d/text()".

Comment: Well in that case I only see constructing a new document or document fragment with `c` or a deep clone of `c` and then applying your XPath to that newly created document or document fragment. XPath won't change its semantics, a path starting with `/` selects  from the root node of the context node and not from the context node.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it is not feasible in my case because the xml is huge. Concurrent clients have their own "view" on it (i.e. they see an internal node as their root node) and doing a copy for each xpath query degrades performances.
I found that calling
xmlXPathNewContext( node);
instead of 
xmlXPathNewContext(  node->doc );
does the trick.
It's dirty but valgrind does not complains...
Anyway in this case the problem is: cannot use xpath like "/a/c/d", but only "/c/d", i.e. root node cannot be part of the xpath.

Comment: It seems your question and desired solution is very specific to libxml, now as you have found a solution, do you think my answer and our exchange of comments has any value for others having the same problem in the future? Otherwise I will simply delete my answer.

Comment: I think it could be useful: other users can choose to do a copy as you suggested or use my workaround (if they accept to loose the root tag in the xpath).
Also, following our discussion I hope someone else can improve my workaroud to don't loose the chance to use the root tag in the xpath query.